# Where to adjust presets for slider options "auto rotate" (3, 5, 10, 15 seconds)?

Tags: options, settings-api, slideshow

I’m currently helping somebody out with their wp installation – and we’re a bit puzzled with the presets for a slider / corousel. The theme in use *Stockholm*, featuring the *Visual Composer* plugin.

In the settings for a slide show element (“gallery" / "flex slider") I see the options for auto rotate “3, 5, 10, 15” seconds. Now (of course) we would like to have the images changing at 7 seconds. Where could I possibly add more steps to the auto rotate options?

[image]

I checked many of the plugin and theme files, but couldn't find anything useful. I also got in contact with the folks at Visual Composer – but only through invato's comment function: their reply "*you can use our API to extend capabilities of VC and it’s elements. Please look into [kb.wpbakery.com](http://kb.wpbakery.com) for more information*" didn't lead me anywhere. Under that url I can not find any info about the actual API – at least nothing that would look useful to me, concerning the presets of a slider.

I suppose discussing specific plugins and/or theme related problems is probably considered '*off topic*' – but I'm currently not even sure if this is actually plugin related – or if it is instead a WP preset…?! I just hope that somebody else had the same problem before and knows where to look – what hook and/or filter to use to alter the slider presets… Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In anybody needs this in the future I found a quick and easy workaround: you could just adjust the slider interval in the shortcode.

First you have to switch to the "classic mode" (turn the Visual Composer off) and then find the shortcode that defines the interval:

```
[vc_gallery interval="10" images="22390,23006" img_size="full"]
```

You can then set the interval to whatever you like – for example 7 seconds:

```
[vc_gallery interval="7" images="22390,23006" img_size="full"]
```